# cross_validate and # of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get precision, recall, f1 score of my bert model using Kfold cross validation.
My input and label shape worked well when I use model.fit() without Kfold. But with Kfold in sklearn it throws an error. Below is my code.

```
input_ids = []
attention_masks = []
token_type_ids = []
all_data_labels = []

for all_sent, all_label in tqdm(zip(all_data["symptom"], all_data["label"]), total=len(all_data)):
    try:
        input_id, attention_mask, token_type_id = bert_tokenizer(all_sent, MAX_LEN)
        
        input_ids.append(input_id)
        attention_masks.append(attention_mask)
        token_type_ids.append(token_type_id)
        all_data_labels.append(all_label)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(all_sent)
        pass

all_symptom_input_ids = np.array(input_ids, dtype=int)
all_symptom_attention_masks = np.array(attention_masks, dtype=int)
all_symptom_type_ids = np.array(token_type_ids, dtype=int)
all_symptom_inputs = (all_symptom_input_ids, all_symptom_attention_masks, all_symptom_type_ids)

all_data_labels = np.asarray(all_data_labels, dtype=np.int32)

class TFBertClassifier(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model_name, dir_path, num_class):
        super(TFBertClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.bert = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name, cache_dir=dir_path)
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(self.bert.config.hidden_dropout_prob)
        self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_class, 
                                                kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(self.bert.config.initializer_range), 
                                                name="classifier")
        
    def call(self, inputs, attention_mask=None, token_type_ids=None, training=False):
        outputs = self.bert(inputs, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
        pooled_output = outputs[1] 
        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output, training=training)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

        return logits

from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def create_model():
    model = TFBertClassifier(model_name='bert-base-multilingual-cased',
                                  dir_path='bert_ckpt',
                                  num_class=num_classes)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(5e-5)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy')
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric], experimental_run_tf_function=False)
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_validate
scoring = {'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score),
           'recall' : make_scorer(recall_score), 
           'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score)}

kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=1234)
results = model_selection.cross_validate(estimator=model,
                                        X=all_symptom_inputs,
                                        y=all_data_labels,
                                        cv=kfold,
                                        scoring=scoring)
```

and below is the error. all inputs are shaped as [3,None] and I can't find why this error is thrown.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9559fde88ed9> in <module>()
     10                                           y=all_data_labels,
     11                                           cv=kfold,
---> 12                                           scoring=scoring)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 51134]
```

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your input is currently the tuple `(all_symptom_input_ids, all_symptom_attention_masks, all_symptom_type_ids)`, but the `KFold` input is looking for an iterable where each element is a **single** example.

What you'd want to do is to convert the inputs to a list of tuples where each element is a single example.

```py
all_symptom_inputs = np.array(list(zip(
    all_symptom_input_ids,
    all_symptom_attention_masks,
    all_symptom_type_ids
)))
```

The above operation might be slow if you're input is very large, so I'd recommend trying something more efficient like numpy's `stack` function (I think `np.stack(..., axis=-1).` might work here).

Comment: I've tried this and now it throws error

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 30 and 3 for '{{node tf_bert_classifier_10/tf_bert_model_10/bert/embeddings/add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](tf_bert_classifier_10/tf_bert_model_10/bert/embeddings/Identity, tf_bert_classifier_10/tf_bert_model_10/bert/embeddings/position_embeddings/embedding_lookup/Identity_1)' with input shapes: [?,3,30,768], [1,3,768]`